# search in a substring(word) in string which is located as a subfield of a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to pull out all the documents of collectionin  which those documents in any subfield(dialogue.text) have a certain word.

my example document is something like this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60fd992366a307a689b58987"
    },
    "id": "1objOZYLF5fdz3WykWo",
    "name": "bbb.mp4",
    "dialogue": [{
        "type": "cue",
        "data": {
            "start": 2378,
            "end": 3211,
            "text": "[ footsteps approaching ]"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "cue",
        "data": {
            "start": 3295,
            "end": 4587,
            "text": "morty, you got to come on."
        }
    }, {
        "type": "cue",
        "data": {
            "start": 4672,
            "end": 6130,
            "text": "you got to come with me."
        }
    }, {
        "type": "cue",
        "data": {
            "start": 6215,
            "end": 7048,
            "text": "what's going on?"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "cue",
        "data": {
            "start": 7132,
            "end": 8049,
            "text": "i got a surprise for you, morty."
        }
    }]
}
```

How could I pull out, for example, all the documents in any dialogue.text field has word "surprise".

suppose I create the index for the dialogue field how could I use "$text" for finding the documents

And if there is any advice for making a better and efficient document in the first place, it is also appreciated.

Should I use SQL-based DB for faster querying or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it the first place, use this to make the index for the text field. if you don't run this you cant search text in the field:

```
  db
      .collection.yourCollection
      .createIndex({ "dialogue.data.text": "text" });
```

and after making the index you can search:

```
   db
      .collection.yourCollection
      .find({ $text: { $search: "your word" } })
      .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is using [Text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/).

> MongoDB provides a good technique that is text search. Using this
> technique we can find a piece of text or a specified word from the
> string fields. Or in other words, MongoDB allows you to perform a
> query operation to find the specified text from the string. In
> MongoDB, we can perform text search using text index and $text
> operator

In case if you need regex find, you can do

```
db.collection.find({
  "dialogue.data.text": {
    $regex: "surprise",
    $options: "g"
  }
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BPs2RhAeo-x)**

Comment: thank you for your help...but I think regex could take a long time even with a quite small db.

Comment: I already mentioned text search is good approach. Bcs its using index, it should be fast. I mentioned regex just to remind you this approch also existing